# Automatically highlight Duplicate Values with Various colors

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have these spreadsheet file for late payers (which is normally 20+ every month). What I want to do is be able to automatically format duplicate values in different colors. Here is the VBA code I use (From other site):

```
Sub ColorCompanyDuplicates()
    'Updateby Extendoffice 20160704

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xChar As String
    Dim xCellPre As Range
    Dim xCIndex As Long
    Dim xCol As Collection
    Dim I As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
        xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
    Else
        xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
    End If

    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xCIndex = 2
    Set xCol = New Collection

    For Each xCell In xRg     
        On Error Resume Next

        xCol.Add xCell, xCell.Text
        If Err.Number = 457 Then
            xCIndex = xCIndex + 1
            Set xCellPre = xCol(xCell.Text)
            If xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xCIndex
            xCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex
        ElseIf Err.Number = 9 Then
            MsgBox "Too many duplicate companies!", vbCritical, "Kutools for Excel"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        On Error GoTo 0
    Next  
End Sub
```

This is a sample File:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ltdg.png)

What I'm having problem is:

- My range is A2:L50 but it colors the blank cells with Red (Although I already fixed it with Conditional Formatting values that are blank)
- It doesn't automatically runs the VBA or make format duplicate cells when I make a change, I have to manually run the module after each change.
- I can't assign colors to each people as we have 100+ people renting for us

Anyway, I hope someone can help me figure this out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please verify I have formatted your code correctly.

Comment: You also have an On Error at the top which wasn't closed before opening a new On Error Resume Next. Not sure second was needed but first needed closing.

Comment: I tried it, it's not working. It doesn't format duplicate cells automatically. Would you want me to a macro-file? Thanks

Comment: Hi, Are you saying the formatting has changed something (it shouldn't have....I hope. But I can roll-back the changes) or that you changing the On Error part means has stopped working? I have only changed the spacing and indenting of your code. I haven't added or amended any functionality.

Comment: Well is there a reason for using VBA? Why don't you use [Conditional Formatting to highlight duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-conditional-formatting-in-excel-34402f91-c7e7-4060-944c-65d913033d18) instantly and automatically?

Comment: I tried and run the code, when I input a new data on a new cell, it format the new data in Red, even if it's a unique or a duplicate value

Comment: Ideally what I want to do is to be able to use different colors of each tenants, using conditional formatting will only highlight or duplicate values with same color, or if I want to have a unique color for each, then I would have to create a conditional format to all of our 100+ tenants lol

Comment: Well but running that code automatically on any cell change can make your workbook responding unbelievable slow (if there are more than a few data rows in it). So I suggest to only run it manually.

Comment: I doubt that using 100+ different colors makes it easier to view your sheet (unless you just like the beauty of colorful sheets). It seems pretty useless to me. So best approach would be using built in conditional formatting and a single color for all duplicates.

Comment: I didn't say though we get 100+ late payers in a month, we only get 20+ or so.  Plus yes I do love beautiful spreadsheets 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your 3 questions

1. To not color empty cells just test for empty cells with `If xCell.Value <> vbNullString Then` (see code below)
2. Another issue is that there are only [56 different colors in the color index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/colorindex-property). You start with color index = 2 (to spare out black and white) so you actually have 54 colors left. If there are more duplicates than 54 they can not be colored differently and you need to start re-using colors you already used before.

   ```
   If xCIndex > 56 Then xCIndex = 2  '(see code below)
   ```

   So coloring will not be unique anymore.

   But you should think about that generally. Because using more then 10 or 15 colors doesn't make your worksheet clearer. If there are more then 10 colors I don't see any benefit in the different coloring at all.
3. Running that code automatically on any cell change can make your workbook responding unbelievable slow (if there are more than a few data rows in it). So I suggest to only run it manually (using a button or shortcut).
   But you can try running it in in a `Worksheet_Change` event. But I think that would be just too slow.

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
       ColorCompanyDuplicates
   End Sub
   ```

   If you run it automatically you probably want to remove the dialog box and remove coloring before re-coloring:

   ```
   Set xRg = Range(xTxt) 'replace the original "Set xRg" line
   If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   xRg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'remove old coloring
   ```

---

This is the changed code part from 1 and 2:

```
    If xCell.Value <> vbNullString Then 'skip coloring empty cells

        xCol.Add xCell, xCell.Text
        If Err.Number = 457 Then
            xCIndex = xCIndex + 1
            If xCIndex > 56 Then xCIndex = 2 'start re-using colors
            Set xCellPre = xCol(xCell.Text)
            If xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xCIndex
            xCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex
        ElseIf Err.Number = 9 Then
            MsgBox "Too many duplicate companies!", vbCritical, "Kutools for Excel"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End If
```

Comment: @Bash Well I tested it and it did work. Then you did something wrong, or the cells are not empty.

Comment: @Bash If it solved your issue please consider marking the answer as solution.

Comment: the first two worked! Thanks! But where do I put the 3rd code?

Comment: @Bash Into the VBA code of that worksheet that needs to be colored (not into a module). But I warn you that this might be slow.

Comment: @Bash Please see my edit about running it automatically (remove the dialog box and fix recoloring by removing old coloring first).

Comment: The only thing I noticed is when I removed the cell value and run the code again, the format remains, the cell is still coloured even with no value

Comment: Then you did not apply my last edit (in point 3) which removes coloring first before recoloring.

Comment: I'm not running it automatically.

Comment: Well then you will still need this line `xRg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'remove old coloring` below `If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` to remove the old coloring first

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like the following in a helper column B and then using conditional formatting > color scales on that column?

Formula to drag down (amend range as required)

```
=IF(MATCH(A1,$A$1:$A$11,0)*IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$11,A1)>1,1,)>0,MATCH(A1,$A$1:$A$11,0)*IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$11,A1)>1,1,),"")
```

**Data layout:**

[image: Data and formatting]

Comment: I'll try helper column if nothing works out. Thanks!

Comment: Just it is a simple way to use the optimized existing functionality of excel.